# How do you use multiple .py files in Python?

Tags: python

I'm messing around with some Python files and I want to know if you can and how you can reference an external file like in other coding languages so that I can make an application with multiple .py files. I tried looking but I couldn't really understand what it was saying and it wasn't really what I was looking for.

Comment: By using `from module import something`.

Comment: if you have a two files named `something.py` and `main.py` in the same directory, if you want to use something from `something.py` in your `main.py`, just write `from something import *` in `main.py`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import files at the top of your python file.

And then you can run them by calling the function.

```py
import sample  # import sample.py file
import other  # import other.py file
import another  # import another.py file

sample.example()
```

Comment: what function do you mean?